# Error "La función no esta definida" al agregar eventos

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo la siguiente pagina que es para agregar tareas, estoy usando json-server(db.json) y módulos.

Tengo un *form* con un input donde agrego la tarea a realizar, las tareas las guardo en un objeto, para después agregarla a la API con *fetch*, guardo las tareas en la API y las extraigo cuando el documento haya cargado y uso un *forEach* para recorrerlas y mostrarlas en el HTML, estoy usando template literals para crear el código HTML y mostrarlas en un *div* (contenedorTareas).

El problema que tengo es que quiero agregar un evento a un elemento dentro de los *template literals*, al *input checkbox* le agrego un evento con `onClick="completo()"`, pero me sale el error de que **la función no esta definida**, he creado la función en varias partes del código, pero me sale siempre el mismo error. Igual al agregar funciones en cualquier elemento que este en los *template literals*, me sale el mismo error.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto o porque no puedo crearla?.

Este es mi *HTML*:

```html
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row bg-white rounded p-2">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <form class="formulario">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="agregarTarea" class="form-label m-0 mb-2 h4">Tarea</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control tarea mb-3" id="agregar-tarea" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-agregar">Agregar Tarea</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-12 mt-5">
                    <div>
                        <h1>Tareas por realizar</h1>
                        
                        <div class="lista-tareas">
           
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
```

Este es mi **`app.js`**:

```
import { agregarTareas,eliminarTarea,extraerTareas } from "./api.js";

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', extraerLasTareas)
const formulario = document.querySelector('.formulario');
const listaTareas = document.querySelector('.lista-tareas')


formulario.addEventListener('submit', agregarTarea);
listaTareas.addEventListener('click',   eliminarTareaId);


function agregarTarea(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    const tarea = document.querySelector('#agregar-tarea').value;
    if(tarea === ''){
        console.log('Debe agregar una tarea')
        return;
    }

    const tareaObj = {
        tarea
    }

    agregarTareas(tareaObj)

    formulario.reset();
}

async function extraerLasTareas(){
    const tareas = await extraerTareas();
    
    tareas.forEach(tareaIndividual => {
        const {tarea,id} = tareaIndividual;

        const contenedorTareas = document.createElement('div');
        contenedorTareas.classList.add('d-flex', 'justify-content-between', 'flex-direction-column', 'align-items-center' , 'mb-3', 'contenedor');

        contenedorTareas.innerHTML = `
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <input type="checkbox"  id="completo" onClick="completo()">
            </div>

            <div>
                <p class="m-0">${tarea}</p>
            </div>

            <div>
                <a href="#" data-id="${id}"><i class="fas fa-trash btn-eliminar"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        `
        listaTareas.appendChild(contenedorTareas)
    })
}

function completo(){
    console.log('Completo...')
}

function eliminarTareaId(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if(e.target.classList.contains('btn-eliminar')){
        const tareaId = Number(e.target.parentElement.dataset.id);
        eliminarTarea(tareaId)
    }
}
```

Y este es mi **`api.js`**:

```
const url = 'http://localhost:4000/tareas';

export function agregarTareas(tarea){
    try {
        fetch(url, {
            method:'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(tarea),
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        })
    } catch (error) {
       console.log(error) 
    }
}

export async function extraerTareas(){
    try {
        const respuesta = await fetch(url);
        const resultado = await respuesta.json();
        return resultado;
    } catch (error) {   
        console.log(error)
    }
}

export function eliminarTarea(tareaId){
    try {
        fetch(`${url}/${tareaId}`, {
            method:'DELETE',
        })
    } catch (error) {
       console.log(error) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes agregar el event listener al input que está dentro del elemento `contenedorTareas` y luego insertarlo al mismo con `appendChild()` de la siguiente manera:

```javascript
tareas.forEach(tareaIndividual => {
    const {tarea,id} = tareaIndividual;

    const contenedorTareas = document.createElement('div');
     
    const completarTareaInput = document.createElement('input');
    completarTareaInput.addEventListener('click', completo); // Siendo "completo" la funcion que definiste mas abajo en tu código

    contenedorTareas.appendChild(completarTareaInput);
     // Acá tambien puedes hacer lo mismo con los otros elementos que tiene "contenedorTareas", es decir un appendChild.
    listaTareas.appendChild(contenedorTareas)
})
```

Saludos

Comment: si, es lo que hacia, pero no habra forma de hacerlo como puse en la pregunta, desde los template literals, o porque no me deja agregar eventos asi

Comment: Disculpa, pero no entiendo el problema entonces, si con la respuesta dada pudiste solucionar el error y agregar un event listener, qué otra cosa necesitas. Sinceramente no entiendo